# How to implement frame saving without interfering with the main thread in USB camera streaming using OpenCV and Python multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I've been using the following code, available [here](https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40), to stream from a USB camera.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import threading
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# also acts (partly) like a cv.VideoCapture
class FreshestFrame(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, capture, name='FreshestFrame'):
        self.capture = capture
        assert self.capture.isOpened()

        # this lets the read() method block until there's a new frame
        self.cond = threading.Condition()

        # this allows us to stop the thread gracefully
        self.running = False

        # keeping the newest frame around
        self.frame = None

        # passing a sequence number allows read() to NOT block
        # if the currently available one is exactly the one you ask for
        self.latestnum = 0
        
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        super().start()

    def release(self, timeout=None):
        self.running = False
        self.join(timeout=timeout)
        self.capture.release()

    def run(self):
        counter = 0
        while self.running:
            # block for fresh frame
            (rv, img) = self.capture.read()
            assert rv
            counter += 1

            # publish the frame
            with self.cond: # lock the condition for this operation
                self.frame = img if rv else None
                self.latestnum = counter
                self.cond.notify_all()

    def read(self, wait=True, seqnumber=None, timeout=None):
        # with no arguments (wait=True), it always blocks for a fresh frame
        # with wait=False it returns the current frame immediately (polling)
        # with a seqnumber, it blocks until that frame is available (or no wait at all)
        # with timeout argument, may return an earlier frame;
        #   may even be (0,None) if nothing received yet

        with self.cond:
            if wait:
                if seqnumber is None:
                    seqnumber = self.latestnum+1
                if seqnumber < 1:
                    seqnumber = 1
                
                rv = self.cond.wait_for(lambda: self.latestnum >= seqnumber, timeout=timeout)
                if not rv:
                    return (self.latestnum, self.frame)

            return (self.latestnum, self.frame)

def main():
    # these windows belong to the main thread
    cv.namedWindow("frame")

    # open some camera
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)

    # wrap it
    fresh = FreshestFrame(cap)

    # main loop
    # get freshest frame, but never the same one twice (cnt increases)
    # see read() for details
    cnt = 0
    while True:
        # test that this really takes NO time
        # (if it does, the camera is actually slower than this loop and we have to wait!)
        t0 = time.perf_counter()
        cnt,img = fresh.read(seqnumber=cnt+1)
        dt = time.perf_counter() - t0
        if dt > 0.010: # 10 milliseconds
            print("NOTICE: read() took {dt:.3f} secs".format(dt=dt))

        # let's pretend we need some time to process this frame
        print("processing {cnt}...".format(cnt=cnt), end=" ", flush=True)

        cv.imshow("frame", img)
        key = cv.waitKey(200)
        if key == 27:
            break

        print("done!")

    fresh.release()

    cv.destroyWindow("frame")
    cv.destroyWindow("realtime")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My problem is that adding blocking operations, such as, in my case, encoding/saving each frame to disk, will block the loop if I insert them in the main thread, after calling fresh.read(). Where should I insert the frame saving?

I've added the frame saving like in the following excerpt:

```
video = cv.VideoWriter(video_fp,
                       cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 
                       fps,
                       (camera.f.Width.value, camera.f.Height.value), 
                       isColor)
fresh = FreshestFrame(camera)
cnt = 0

while True:
    cnt,frame = fresh.read(seqnumber=cnt+1)
    video.write(frame)
    record_delta = datetime.now() - begin_ts
    record_string = '0' + str(record_delta).split('.', 2)[0]
    screenText('Recording   {}   {}   {}'.format(exp, sub, task), 1, copy, txtsize)
    screenText(record_string, 2, copy, txtsize)
    cv.imshow(wd_title, copy)

    key = cv.waitKey(1)
    wnd = cv.getWindowProperty(wd_title, cv.WND_PROP_VISIBLE)
    if key == 27 or wnd < 1:
        if wnd < 1:
            closed = True
        break
```